# ItemsSource and DataTemplate for Grid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I have an issue with `Grid` and template.
For example. I have a `Grid` with 3 columns and 2 rows. And i have a `List`, which has links to images. And i want to put images from 0 to 6 using tempalate like `ListView`. `Android` `GridView` looks like that fits for my issue, but maybe there are more solutions for this issue. How i can implement this.

Comment: XF Grid doesn't support databinding/templating.  And the Android GridView only applies to Android, not Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Jason i know it, that i ask, maybe some one dealed with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look into XLabs gridview they made something that you need, You can set itemtemplate and itemsource.

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/GridView

Answer (score 0):

Set property `ItemsLayout` of type `GridItemsLayout` inside collection view. It has two other properties: `Orientation` and `Span`. Property `Orientation` can be `"Vertical"` to expand vertically and to fill row-wise from `ItemsSource`, or `"Horizontal"` to expand grid horizontally and to fill column-wise from `ItemsSource`. Property `Span` specifies number of cells per row for vertical orientation and per column for horizontal orientation.

This example makes three columns grid for `CollectionView`:

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
       <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="3" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Have a look at specify collectionview layout article from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout.